# algorithm for proportional distribution

Tags: algorithm

Let's say there are `n` bins, as container for cash

each bin must hold notes for the same denominations `$100`, `$20`, `$5`, `$1`

and then now there is a total amount defined, say `$27,869`

also there is proportion `MUST BE` required for each bin can split, say

```
`30%` for `$100`, 
`40%` for `$20`, 
`20%` for `$5`, 
`10%` for `$1`,
```

so all 4 bins make up the entire (`100%`) of the final amount that closest to required amount

finally the algorithm MUST return the closest optimized amount, say may be
`$26,982`

I was thinking about using recursive function, go through from largest denomination to smallest denomination, but I don't know how to resolve with the proportion, please enlighten me. Any Java/C or pseudo code is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify... the percentages are the percentage of the total dollar value, or total number of bills?  Is the output the number of bills in each bin?  Are the percentages given known to be solvable?  In other words, if the given dollar amount is $1, can we be given a non-zero percentage for any of the non-$1 bins?

Comment: Divide percentages by their gcd, multiply with corresponding amount and sum up to get the smallest possible amount (391). Divide the target amount by that, round and multiply again (solution is 27761).

Answer (score 0):

If your percentages need to be precise, you'll have a very limited number of combinations you can use.

In your example, you would always have exactly 3 times as many $100 bills as $1 bills, for example.

In general, I would find the denomination with the lowest percentage, start with 1 bill, determine how many of each other bill you need for that, until you exceed the total value.

For each other denomination, you'd determine the number of bills something like:

```
bills100 = Math.round(bills1 * percent100/percent1)
```

Note that, in general, your percentages won't be exact, but they will be as close as possible. No, I won't write the code for you.